# Get separate graphed lines for different variables

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

I have a variable `data` with the following structure:

```
week: int 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
earn: int 2 3 2 7 8 9 2 6 4 2 ...
name: chr "C", "A", "C", "A" ...
```

Each name (person) has a week with what they earned. So from the above we can see that C earned 2 in week 1 while A earned 3 in week 1. C earned 2 in week two while A earned 7 in week too.

I wish to plot this on a line graph. The below is what I have tried.

```
p <- plot.ly(data, x = data$week, name = "Week", type = "scatter", mode = "lines") %>%
    add_trace(y = data$earn, name = "earn", mode = "lines+markers) %>%
    add_trace(y = data$earn, name = "earn", mode = "markers")

p
```

However, this gives a graph with one line where the marker for week one has (2,3) as this is both the earning on this week. However I would like two lines so it can be clearly seen the difference in earnings for both names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining color will give you what you want.

```
p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~week, y = ~ earn) %>%
    add_lines(color = ~name) %>% 
    add_markers(color = ~name, showlegend = FALSE)
p
```

alternatively you can also use:

```
p <- plot_ly(data=data, x = ~week, y = ~ earn) %>%
    add_traces(color = ~name, mode = "lines+markers")
p
```

Comment: This works. However, in the legend I get two lines showing the color with both names and also two markers showing the color with both names. Is it possible to just the color once for each name rather than twice?

Comment: @petermark, see edit. if you add showlegend = FALSE to the first example, one one legend will be showed